# Calculating Session Duration for Single Page Website (Google Analytics)

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads, remarketing

I'm trying to set up some remarketing lists in Adwords and I'd like to target people who've been on my site for over 15 seconds.

The problem is that I am sending traffic to single-page landing pages, so people will watch the video on the page, scroll through the content and then click the back arrow, giving me (if I'm correct) a bounce and 0 time for the session.

Do I need to create custom events that fire when somebody clicks anything on the page, or scrolls past 100 pixels on the page? Will that allow Google to log the session duration when they ultimately click the back arrow?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, custom events would solve the problem.

> Please, check [Non-Interaction Events](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033068?hl=en#NonInteractionEvents) in order to understand that you can create events that do not affect time or bounce.

In this case, I will use the following:

- Event on scroll (more than 50% of the site).
- Event on time (depends on the video. You can use [setTimeOut](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)).
- Event on video player (play/stop with Non-Interaction, just to know how they use it).

Comment: Thanks. Just to be clear, in my case I do want these to be "interaction events", correct? Otherwise setting up event on scroll, etc. won't have the intended effect of showing me the "real" time on site.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Scroll and time must be "interaction" and the player "non-interaction".